# How to say "viral" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, modern-life

Consider the phrase:

> The video went viral

How could the concept of "[viral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_phenomenon)" in the above meaning be expressed in Latin?

This is clearly a recent word, so there will not be a native one. *Virus* is a native Latin word, but, [as far as I can see](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvirus) it does not mean virus in the biological sense (which is from where the properties of "viral" are derived, as far as I understand). The wikipedia entry for virus in Latin is titled [*virus biologicum*](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_biologicum).

There are several words for "quickly" which could be used for a combined term, e.g. *celeriter*, *rapidus*, *velox*. *Amplus* is another interesting term, which [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amplus#Latin) suggests to mean

> 3. (figuratively, of force) impetuous, violent, strong

But simply translating viral with *amplus* seems not precise enough. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to suggest that the rumour/ message / fashion has a mind of its own then *Amplus* sounds good. You might also check up on *Pernix,* (spelling:PERNIX not PEMIX) and *Percitus.* All suggest 'eagerness.'

Alternatively, there are intensifiers which can be added to words for 'speedy,' *celer;* 'speedily,' *celeriter;* 'speed,' *celeritas,* gen. *celeritatis.*
*perceler,*
*praevelox,*
*praerapidus.*

*Rumor* itself comes from *ruo, ruere,* to rush.